# How to scrape this pdf file?

Tags: python-3.x

I want to scrape tables of this persian pdf file and get the results as a pandas dataframe but I get error "NameError: name 'PDFResourceManager' is not defined" and no good content is extracted.
please help me to find a true encoded solution for it. Including your tested code is appreciated.

```
from pdfminer.converter import TextConverter
from io import StringIO
from io import open
from urllib.request import urlopen
import pdfminer as pm

urlpdf="https://www.codal.ir/Reports/DownloadFile.aspx?id=jck8NF9OtmFW6fpyefK09w%3d%3d"
response = requests.get(urlpdf, verify=False, timeout=5)
f=io.BytesIO(response.content)
def readPDF(f):
    rsrcmgr=PDFResourceManager()
    retstr=StringIO()
    laparams=LAParams()
    device=TextConverter(rsrcmgr,retstr,laparams=laparams)
    process_pdf(rsrcmgr,device,pdfFile)
    device.close()
    content=retstr.getvalue()
    retstr.close()
    return content
pdfFile=urlopen(urlpdf)
outputString=readPDF(pdfFile)

proceedings=outputString.encode('utf-8') # creates a UTF-8 byte object
proceedings=str(proceedings) # creates string representation <- the source of your issue
file=open("extract.txt","w", encoding="utf-8") # encodes str to platform specific encoding.
file.write(proceedings)
file.close()
```

Comment: Where did you expect `PDFResourceManager` to come from? Like the error message says, it is not defined anywhere in this code.

Comment: this is my question also. If I knew, I would have solved my problem.